# Google voice in windows phone

Tags: apps, google

Is there any Google Voice app for Windows? If I have a Google number am I able to receive call on my Windows phone, that can enable free calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google has blocked third party apps from connecting to their Voice service. And since Google does not build apps for Windows Phone there are no Google Voice apps currently in the store.

More info: http://www.windowscentral.com/new-policy-google-voice-means-end-metrotalk-windows-phone

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an app according to [an article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160423170324/http://www.examiner.com/article/windows-phone-owners-rejoice-google-voice-mobile-ready-lieu-of-app) published by Examiner. It gives the following steps:

> 1. Point your mobile browser to https://www.google.com/voice/m and login into your Google Voice page with your Gmail user name and password. Choice the option so the mobile web page remembers your login.
> 2. Store the Web page as a permanent app by pinning it to your start menu.
> 3. To differentiate between your cell phone calls and those from your Google Voice number point either your mobile or desktop browser
>      to https://www.google.com/voice?pli=1#inbox. Under Settings choose Calls. Under Caller ID (incoming) choose, "Display my Google Voice number." Under the Phone tab enable, "Receive text messages on this phone" as well as "Notify me of new voicemails via text."